# What is a Semicoroutine?

Tags: ruby

I've been studying fibers in Ruby, and the term semicoroutine has come up. What is meant by a semicoroutine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/08/ruby-1-9-fibers).
Essentially, it's code that can suspend itself, and it's caller can resume execution at the point the code suspended.